# Important and handy tools and commands while developing C applications in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I have had experience using Visual Studio till now. But I am intending to use a few Linux tools to develop and maintain applications which are written in C.

I went thorough this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228/what-tools-do-you-use-to-develop-c-applications-on-linux) but it talks too much about the IDE's. I am happy to use them but I wanted to know which other tools are handy and important for the above excercise. I would also like to know incase there are any commands which would make things easy. Thanks!

EDIT:  I have used vim and familiar with gcc and its important flags. anything further would help.

Comment: Wondring whether this question was more for the community wiki.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will want to familiarize yourself with the linux command line tools. In particular:

- Learn a good editor such as `vim` or `emacs`
- Script your builds using `make`
- Compile using `gcc`
- Debug using `gdb`
- Source control: if you have the luxury of choosing one, I recommend a modern DVCS such as git or mercurial. Otherwise whatever tool your team is already using should be fine.

This is just scratching the surface of the essentials, but it may help you get started.

---

These tools are also very useful:

- `grep` - You  need a good way to search through source files. This command is integrated with vim and emacs (?) so you will probably want to use it directly from your editor in most cases.
- `ctags` - As others have said, this will make it *much* easier to navigate through your source code from your editor. Again, consult your editor for exactly how to work with ctags.
- `valgrind` - To find memory leaks in your application.
- `lint` - A static analysis tool such as [splint](http://www.splint.org/) to find coding mistakes in your C code.
- `rpm` or another packaging system - Depending upon how you will deploy your application, you may want to use a package manager to help with versioning, install/upgrade scripts, etc.
- `screen` - A terminal multiplexer allows you to split up your terminal so you can (for example) look at your source code in one pane and debug/execute/search logs in another. This is also handy if you have to connect to any remote machines your are supporting, since if you happen to get disconnected you can just reconnect to your remote screen session later, without having to worry about all of your commands being terminated. For example, if you are in the middle of a `yum update` you do not have to worry about it being terminated mid-transaction just because your connection was severed.
- `ssh` / `sftp` / etc - To securely copy files to your test/production machines, if necessary.

Comment: yeah thanks! I have used vim and familiar with gcc and its important flags. anything further would help. Thanks!

Comment: @Shash - No problem, I added some more tools for you :)

Comment: +1 for `screen` (and +1 again for `ssh`)

Comment: +1 for DVCS, `screen` and all the other awesome tools. Although I prefer graphical editors like `geany` (for GTK environment) or `kile` (for QT environment). What about the `valgrind` family?

Comment: @JonasWielicki - Good point, I included `valgrind` as well as `lint`.

Comment: I think `cscope` should be in the list as well.

Answer (score 6):

This tools are useful when developing in C under Linux:

1. IDE : `Vim` with `solarized` theme (http://ethanschoonover.com/). `Ctgas` and `Taglist` to navigate easily through your code(http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/)
2. For compiling and dubugging `gcc`, `gdb`, `make`
3. For big projects : `AUTOCONF`, `AUTOMAKE`, and `LIBTOOL`
4. To check for all memory related stuff : `Valgrind`
   To check functions CPU time consumption `Callgrind` (http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html)
   And globally `Valgrind's Tool Suite` (http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) is a great tool
5. For high quality code : `GNU gcov`(Test coverage), this is a great article on code testing and high quality C code (http://aleccolocco.blogspot.fr/2009/08/sqlite-lesson-in-low-defect-software.html)
6. `GNU locate` : To find easily all files
7. `Git` for source code configuration
8. `Doxygen` : to generate documentation for the code
9. If you develop network programs : `wireshrak`, `tcpdump`
10. Esaily navigate through kernel code with `LXR`(http://lxr.linux.no) (http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~niehaus/classes/800-s04/notes/setup_lxr.txt)
11. `Strace` to trace system calls(It is always a good tool to debug programs that open configuration files)

`MAN PAGES` is the best tool

And a lot of other good stuff :-

Answer (score 2):

Using terminator for multi terms and easy switch while using processus or htop.

I recommend emacs (-nw) or vi

Gcc to compile your C code.

You also want to use GDB for debug.

Valgrind to check leak and memory dump

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to find stuff in your codebase, and for that I'd recommend:

1. [ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com). It's like a `find`/`grep` combination, but much easier to use, much more useful and geared directly towards programmers.
2. [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). It will help you navigate through your codebase via your editor (vi/emacs etc.) in a asimilar fashion to IDEs (treating code as a set of hyperlinks)